# Subviews on UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I was wondering: in Apple's "Photos" app, when the user wishes to share more than one photo, he or she can tap on the individual thumbnails, and a check in a red circle will appear on top of each one, indicating that they've been selected for sharing. Is there any way to mimic this behavior in our apps? By somehow inserting subviews on thumbnails, perhaps...? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't affect the thumbnail views on a UIImagePicker, so you'll have to implement this yourself. It should be pretty straightforward:

- UIScrollView will be the container
- a UIView descendant for each tile, containing

  - UIImageView subview to display the thumbnail
  - UIButton for the clickable checkmark

Make sure you create thumbnails of your images and cache them, and don't shy away from UIImageView - it is heavily optimized.

There is a great sample app in the WWDC sample code re: UIScrollView that should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, I need the user to be able to select photos from any part of his photo library, so I can't really cache all of the  photos. I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: You can generate thumbnails for the images as they are scrolled to, and cache those in your application. If the thumbnails are 20 x 30, the files will be extremely small.